# Array of structs, non constant size

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Is it possible to create an array of structs if you need to change the size of the array depending on the file being used?

Im creating an array of structs but im filling the struct from a file.  I need to make the size of the array depending on how many lines in the file.

----Okay thanks, its a side project im working and didn't use vectors in school.----

Comment: Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Vector, Victor.

Comment: *and didn't use vectors in school* -- This is the sad shape of how C++ is being taught in schools.

Comment: I suspect that here's how C++ is being taught in schools: "Now, open your browser, type www.stackoverflow.com, click 'Ask a question', cut-and-paste your code, and wait for someone to help you".

Comment: If `vector` is off the table it sounds like you need to write one. Several implementations of `vector` are publicly available for you to use as a basis.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik with teachers that learnt C++ this way, why the wonder?

Comment: Honestly, the aversion to the standard library that is still present in academia...

Comment: You can perform dynamic allocation using `new`. You could also implement a linked list class.

Answer (score -1):

Since you haven't learned about the standard library in school, here's a demo of how to create an array (a `std::vector`) of lines from a text file, using the standard library, plus how to handle failures.

The code is not meant to be practical. ***For practical code I'd just use a loop with, in each iteration, `getline` and then `push_back` on the vector.***

Hopefully this gives you some of ideas in that direction, as well as showing what headers are needed for what. :)

```
#include <algorithm>
using std::copy;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::cerr; using std::istream;

#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;

#include <stdexcept>
using std::exception; using std::runtime_error;

#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_xxx

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <iterator>
using std::back_inserter; using std::istream_iterator;

auto hopefully( bool const e ) -> bool { return e; }
auto fail( string const& message ) -> bool { throw runtime_error( message ); }

class Line
{
private:
    string  chars_;

public:
    operator string& () { return chars_; }
    operator string const& () const { return chars_; }
    //operator string&& () && { return chars_; }

    friend
    auto operator>>( istream& stream, Line& line )
        -> istream&
    {
        getline( stream, line.chars_ );
        hopefully( stream.eof() or not stream.fail() )
            || fail( "Failed reading a line with getline()" );
        return stream;
    }
};

void cppmain( char const filename[] )
{
    ifstream f( filename );
    hopefully( not f.fail() )
        || fail( "Unable to open the specified file." );

    // This is one way to create an array of lines from a text file:
    vector<string> lines;
    using In_it = istream_iterator<Line>;
    copy( In_it( f ), In_it(), back_inserter( lines ) );

    for( string const& s : lines )
    {
        cout << s << "\n";
    }
}

auto main( int n_args, char** args )
    -> int
{
    try
    {
        hopefully( n_args == 2 )
            || fail( "You must specify a (single) file name." );
        cppmain( args[1] );
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        cerr << "!" << x.what() << "\n";
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```